# Microsoft official site for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Does Microsoft has got any official forum site or dedicated site for SQL Server?

Like they have for [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net) for ASP.NET, [www.iis.net](http://www.iis.net) for IIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has several web sites on SQL Server which targets different audience profiles.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/default.aspx is the official product site.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/category/sqlserver/ is the sql server forum. Please keep in mind that technet and msdn forums also contains sql server sections.

http://www.sqlpass.org/ is a microsoft supported world-wide sql server community and it has local chapters in almost every country.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server[Forums & Blogs](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/community/forums-and-blogs.aspx)